# Web scraping script crashes after a few loops

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been learning to code for the last couple of months and, even though I've been pretty sucessful so far, I am stuck with my latest script.

Just learned how to scrape websites for basic stuff and made a script that saves an image from a page and goes to the next image on a loop. However, after a few loops the script crashes and gives this error message back:

```
2020-06-03 19:41:03,243 -  DEBUG-  #######Res sURL=https://xkcd.com/2277/
2020-06-03 19:41:03,245 -  DEBUG-  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): xkcd.com:443
2020-06-03 19:41:03,781 -  DEBUG-  https://xkcd.com:443 "GET /2276/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2607
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ivanx/PycharmProjects/strong passworddetection/xkcd.py", line 15, in <module>
    comicURL = 'https:'+ elms[0].get('src')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have no idea what is wrong, any advise?

The whole script is as follows:

```
import requests, bs4, logging, os
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s -  %(levelname)s-  %(message)s')

os.makedirs('xkcd', exist_ok=True)

sURL = 'https://xkcd.com/'

logging.debug('Start of the while loop')
while not sURL.endswith('#'):
site = requests.get(sURL)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(site.text, 'html.parser')
elms = soup.select('#comic > img')

comicURL = 'https:'+ elms[0].get('src')

res = requests.get(comicURL)
res.raise_for_status()

imgFile = open(os.path.join('xkcd', os.path.basename(comicURL)), 'wb')

for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
    imgFile.write(chunk)
imgFile.close()

logging.debug('#######Res sURL=' + str(sURL))
nElms = soup.select('#middleContainer > ul:nth-child(4) > li:nth-child(2) > a')
pURL = 'https://xkcd.com'+nElms[0].get('href')
sURL = pURL
```

Also, I forgot to add that if I try to start the loop on image 2276, like this:

```
sURL = 'https://xkcd.com/2276'
```

I get this error:

```
2020-06-03 19:53:26,245 -  DEBUG-  Start of the while loop
2020-06-03 19:53:26,248 -  DEBUG-  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): xkcd.com:443
2020-06-03 19:53:26,766 -  DEBUG-  https://xkcd.com:443 "GET /2276 HTTP/1.1" 301 178
2020-06-03 19:53:26,790 -  DEBUG-  https://xkcd.com:443 "GET /2276/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2607
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ivanx/PycharmProjects/strong passworddetection/xkcd.py", line 15, in <module>
    comicURL = 'https:'+ elms[0].get('src')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that because your call to the selector returns a 0 element list.

on the page https://xkcd.com/2276, you can see that the 'comic' div looks like this:

```
<div id="comic">
<a href="https://twitter.com/kakape/status/1235319133585248259"><img src="//imgs.xkcd.com/comics/self_isolate.png" title="Turns out I&#39;ve been &quot;practicing social distancing&quot; for years without even realizing it was a thing!" alt="Self-Isolate" srcset="//imgs.xkcd.com/comics/self_isolate_2x.png 2x"/></a>
</div>
```

Because the img is wrapped in an anchor tag, the entire thing is the child, not the image.

To select the image element for this structure, use this selector:

```
elms = soup.select('#comic img')
```

This will select any img contained in the comic div.

Comment: Oh, man... I swear to you I have been looking for differences in the HTML code for the last 36hrs... it was there all along. Sorry and thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

I ran your **scraper** for some time, and there are few bugs (I left the comments - sometimes there aren't any images, so you need to check for that too):

```
import requests, bs4, logging, os
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s -  %(levelname)s-  %(message)s')

os.makedirs('xkcd', exist_ok=True)

sURL = 'https://xkcd.com/'

logging.debug('Start of the while loop')

while not sURL.endswith('#'):
    logging.debug('#######Res sURL=' + str(sURL))
    site = requests.get(sURL)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(site.text, 'html.parser')
    img = soup.select_one('#comic img')                 #  <--- remove < in the selector

    if img:                                             #  <--- Sometimes there's only text, no <IMG>
        comicURL = 'https:'+ img['src']

        res = requests.get(comicURL)
        res.raise_for_status()

        imgFile = open(os.path.join('xkcd', os.path.basename(comicURL)), 'wb')

        for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
            imgFile.write(chunk)
        imgFile.close()
    else:
        logging.debug('### IMAGE NOT FOUND ###')


    pURL = 'https://xkcd.com' + soup.select_one('.comicNav a[rel="prev"]')['href']  # <-- change in selector for previous link
    sURL = pURL
```